# Cosa significa "forca" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Sto leggendo *La Locandiera* di Carlo Goldoni. La mia domanda è sulla scena nella quale il Conte d'Albafiorita offre degli orecchini di diamanti a Mirandolina, la locandiera. Ecco la risposta di Mirandolina e del Cavaliere di Ripafratta, personaggio misogino che ha una grande antipatia per la locandiera, e anche del Marchese di Forlipopoli, un nobile pretendente di Mirandolina ma senza un soldo:

> MIRANDOLINA: Perché mi vuol ella donare quegli
>   orecchini?
>
> MARCHESE: Veramente sarebbe un gran regalo! Ella
>   ne ha de' più belli al doppio.
>
> CONTE: Questi sono legati alla moda. Vi prego riceverli per amor mio.
>
> CAVALIERE: (Oh che pazzo!). (*Da sé.*)
>
> MIRANDOLINA: No, davvero, signore...
>
> CONTE: Se non li prendete, mi disgustate.
>
> MIRANDOLINA: Non so che dire... mi preme tenermi
>   amici gli avventori della mia locanda. Per non disgustare il signor Conte, li prenderò.
>
> CAVALIERE: (Oh che forca!). (*Da sé*.)

Il quesito è sul significato della parola "forca" in questa frase pronunciata dal Cavaliere. Nella [voce "forca" del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/forca/) si può leggere:

> *faccia da f.*, oggi meno com. che *arnese*, *avanzo*, *faccia da galera*; usato assol. e riferito a persona, uomo degno della galera: *è una f.* (anche come titolo d’ingiuria: *forca!*); con senso attenuato, di ragazzo impertinente, indisciplinato: *quel figliolo è una vera forca*.

Significa questo che il Cavaliere pensa che la locandiera è una persona degna della galera per quello che ha fatto (accettare gli orecchini di diamanti dal Conte)?

Answer (score 3):

Penso che l'esclamazione si riferisca alla lingua biforcuta (non sincera) della locandiera. Come spiegato sotto 'forca' in senso idiomatico viene usata in questo senso. Il Cavaliere misogino esclama :"***oh che lingua biforcuta!***":

***[Forca](http://unaparolaalgiorno.it/significato/F/forca):***

> - La forca, più che un arnese per spostare paglia e fieno, è una forma archetipica: il manico lungo che infine si separa in più denti richiama l'incrocio di una strada, il delta di un fiume, un valico stretto.
> - ***E infatti il nome di questo attrezzo suggerisce fantasiose espressioni idiomatiche, legate alla sua terminazione biforcuta***: ad esempio, con "fare la forca" o "fare le forche" si intende "fare il doppio gioco" o "fingere di ignorare qualcosa", mentre parlando di scuola "fare forca" vuol dire non andarci - nel senso che, arrivati al bivio che porta a scuola, si prende l'altra strada.

(unaparolaalgiorno.it)

Comment: Cioè, quello che intende dire il Cavaliere è che la locandiera sta parlando in modo falso?

Comment: Il Cavaliere allude a quanto dice la Locandiera, ossia lei sostiene di accettare gli orecchini solo per non fare dispiacere ad un cliente, mentre sicuramente li accetta perché  sono preziosi.

Comment: Non sono sicuro che si riferisca alla lingua biforcuta, anche se è impossibile dirlo con il solo testo che abbiamo a disposizione. A me pare più un insulto generico (con forca nel senso di strumento per l'impiccagione) ma ovviamente è una questione di interpretazione.

Comment: anche a me convince di più l'ipotesi della "lingua biforcuta", cioè che parla con doppiezza.
Ricordo un'espressione, usata nel doppiaggio di film "western" (quindi in epoca molto più recente) dove spesso gli indiani esclamavano «Uomo bianco, lingua biforcuta».

Comment: Mi sembra troppo forte il riferimento all'impiccagione, mentre dare della lingua biforcuta ad una donna, soprattutto da parte di un misogino, ha più senso a mio avviso.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Posso riportare un brano più ampio. Magari così si capisce meglio. Adesso anche a me (il commento di Fabio mi ha aiutato a capire il significato di "lingua biforcuta") la risposta di Josh61 mi sembra convincente.

Comment: @Charo Conosco molto bene *La locandiera* per cui non c'è bisogno di riportare altri brani :). Volevo solo portare la mia opinione, poi come ho detto è una questione di interpretazione personale, e non è neanche troppo importante per la comprensione del resto della commedia.

Comment: Secondo questo [link](https://renatomastro1954.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/la-locandiera.pdf), "che forca!" è letteralmente “che arnese da forca!”, espressione riportata anche dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/arnese/): "riferito a persona, è sempre spregiativo". Quindi, come detto da @DenisNardin, quello che sappiamo di sicuro è che si tratta di un insulto a Mirandolina. La spiegazione di questa risposta è interessante e anche convincente, ma sono d'accordo con Denis che è difficile stabilire con sicurezza se questo era il significato che Goldoni aveva in mente.